# How to get DateTime stamp from SQL Server DBCC LOG transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, dbcc

I'm using SQL Server 2008 'DBCC LOG(database, 4)' to see a view of transactions in question but do not see a DateTime stamp associated with them. Any idea how to retrieve the Time stamp of a particular transaction?

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/

Comment: Thanks Remus. Just what I was looking for.